# Why is the Date in Row being transformed automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop, winforms-interop

I'm using Miscrosoft Office Interop Excel to sort and manage a ".csv" file and create an excel file.

When I copy one cell that contains a date for example :

> "04/05/2018 18:55"

I substring that into

> "04/05/2018"

and paste it into another cell, it transforms it into this weird number

> 43195

Why is this happening? How can I prevent or modify this? I'm currently passing the info. like this:

```
String date = worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value2.ToString();
worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value2 = date; //this shows up as 43195
```

Comment: Because that's how many days after `1899-12-30` the 5th of April 2018 is obviously (You have to appreciate some Excel and Lotus history to appreciate the significance of that start date). We'd need to see some code to fix (or to judge if there is anything to fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not being transformed really.  Excel actually stores all dates as a number representing the number of days since 1/0/1900 (really!).  What you are seeing in your cell is the raw numeric value representing the date.  If you open your result spreadsheet, highlight your column, right click and select formatting, and select “Date”, you’ll see it display the date you expect.

So you are going to want to do this in your code.  Assuming your date is in column “B” and your worksheet is “ws”:

```
ws.Range[“B:B”].NumberFormat = “mm/dd/yyyy”;
```

This assumes a US date format.

Comment: No, day 0 for Excel is 30th December 1899, not 01/01/1900.

Comment: Your correction is wrong. It really is that screwed up. 30/12/1899 is 0,  31/12/1899 is assigned the value 1, 01/01/1900 is assigned the value 2, and so on up.

Comment: Edited.  It’s really 1/0/1900 which you’ll see if you format 0 as date.  There are 31 days in December, and formatting 1 as date gets you “1/1/1900”

Comment: For en-US locale, Excel 2016, it does exactly as I described in my edit.

Comment: I forgot, Excel does some additional weirdness for backwards compatibility. If you're going to actually say it's the days since 1/0/1900 you also have to say "including one day for 29th February 1900 which didn't exist". It's easier to say it's days since 1899/12/30 assuming none of your actual dates are from 1900 or earlier and you care about a reproducable formula outside of Exel. (E.g. its that actual value used in COM)

Comment: Fair enough, you are right about the extra leap day, and we aren’t even considering the 1904 based system for Mac compatibility.  All of this is tangential to the original issue posted by @joemartin94 though.

Comment: It is indeed a mess. For the details, see my 2003 article on the subject: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/16/erics-complete-guide-to-vt_date/